# SSIS package error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2014

I've recently modified an existing SSIS package and deployed it to SQL Server 2014.

When I try and execute the package from the Integration services Catalog I get the following error: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON". The connection manager that is generating this error is pointing to a linked 2008 server.

We have other packages that point to the same linked server/database that do not exhibit this particular problem.

In creating the modified package, I did not change the connection managers, just the source components and some of the other tasks.

I'm at a loss why this package would be affected, and no other ones. Anylight someone can shine on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between running the working packages versus this one? Is a proxy involved? Does one specify the username and password and the other does not? What account runs the package that fails?

Comment: In terms of connection managers, none. They are the same. All packages are on the same server, no proxys, all use windows authentication.

The account I'm trying to run it from is my own. I don't have a job set up. I always test by trying to execute the package from the server first before I set up a job..

Comment: And what about an SSIS proxy?  Typically when you schedule an SSIS package with an SQL Agent job, you need to use a service account that's been authorized as an SSIS proxy.

Comment: Consider creating a credential, setting up a proxy, and configuring SQL Server Agent to use the proxy. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204326/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-for-ssis